# booktabs' bottomrule fails with table content via \input

Tags: tables, booktabs

Below code compiles as-is but fails when commenting out the `\input` statement. Why, and how to fix this?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{mwe-bottomrule}
abc \\
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    abc \\
    %\input{mwe-bottomrule}
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `\\` with `\tabularnewline` has no effect. Latest TeXlive on macOS.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567988/2388

Comment: Your code complies fine if I replace `\begin{filecontents*}{mwe-bottomrule}` with `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mwebottomrule.tex}` and `\input{mwe-bottomrule}` with `\input mwebottomrule`.

Comment: @Mico This is also effectively the solution in the linked question (the primitive TeX `\input` fixes the problem).