# Errors using \bottomrule when inserting table

Tags: tables, errors, siunitx, booktabs

EDIT: Added preamble, and it seems `\input table` worked! When I manually insert the table, rather than input it, I do not get any errors, and it looks nice. However, when I use `\input{table.tex}`, I get a host of errors and the PDF won't compile - `Misplaced \noalign, Missing } inserted, Missing } inserted, Misplaced \cr, Misplaced \cr.` I don't have the problem for `\toprule`, and I do use the packages siunitx and booktabs.

Here is the code to generate the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%% links
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

%% maths
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}


%% basic layout formatting  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % full-width
    \topskip        =   20pt
    \parskip        =   10pt
    \parindent      =   0 pt
    \baselineskip   =   15pt

\usepackage{setspace}            % line spacing
    \onehalfspacing

\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}            % to reset the headers of tables 
\usepackage{rotating}           % for sidewaystable
\usepackage{siunitx}

\numberwithin{table}{section}    % reset the Table numbering for each section

%% these three are essential for estout
\usepackage{booktabs}  % neatly formatting lines
\usepackage{threeparttable}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}    % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

%% bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

%%%% TABLE 1 %%%%

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Summary statistics} \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
        \toprule
            \input{table.tex}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Here is my table.tex code:

```
                   &           N&        Mean&          SD\\
 \midrule
 w         &    1&        5&        9\\
 x         &    2&        6&        10\\
 y         &    3&        7&      11\\
 z         &    4&        8&      12\\
```

Comment: Can we see your preamble?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ... Your code working fine for me, just a clarification, do you use "booktabs"? Also please provide `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: A complete example would have been nice, but is it possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/567985/107497 ?

Comment: Changing `\input{table.tex}` to `\input table` seems to take care of the problem.

Comment: @HerbSchulz just edited it, sorry about that! Mico's suggestion did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can fully replicate the issue reported by the OP on a MacTeX2021 system, with all updates in place, using the code shown below.

Not sure *why* this works, but replacing `\input{table.tex}` with `\input table` takes care of the issue. (Note that `.tex` is the default filename extension for use with `\input`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{table.tex}
           &    N&     Mean&      SD\\
 \midrule
 w         &    1&        5&       9\\
 x         &    2&        6&      10\\
 y         &    3&        7&      11\\
 z         &    4&        8&      12\\
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Summary statistics} \label{tab:table1}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
    \input table  % not: '\input{table.tex}'
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```